# CMTime in AVPlayer's addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval: callback never reaches item's duration

Tags: ios, objective-c, avplayer, avplayeritem, cmtime

I use AVPlayer's `-(id)addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval: queue: usingBlock:` method to update UI up to playback progress. However, my progress bar never reaches end.

```
CMTime duration = self.player.currentItem.asset.duration;
float totalSeconds = (Float64)(duration.value * 1000) / (Float64)(duration.timescale);
NSLog(@"duration: %.2f", totalSeconds);

__weak __typeof(self) welf = self;

_mTimeObserver = [self.player addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval:CMTimeMake(10, 1000)
                                              queue:NULL // main queue
                                         usingBlock:^(CMTime time) {

  float totalSeconds = (Float64)(time.value * 1000) / (Float64)(time.timescale);
  NSLog(@"progress %f", totalSeconds);

                                                }];
```

logs:

```
App[2373:792179] duration: 3968.00
```

*hit play button*

```
App[2373:792179] progress 0011.176
App[2373:792179] progress 0021.175
...
App[2373:792179] progress 3701.319
App[2373:792179] progress 3704.000
```

Should not I expect last number to be `3968.0` ?

Audio is streamed from server.

**EDIT**

Last progress number is *ALWAYS* `duration - 0.264 sec` whatever actual duration length is.

This is so strange, I wish we could use emoticons on SO.

Answer (score 0):

Good question. Try using `CMTimeGetSeconds(time)` instead of calculating the total seconds yourself.

Additionally, try to use `CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(10.0, NSEC_PER_SEC)` to create the time for the periodic time observer.

This post helped me a lot to wrap my head around the enigma that is CMTime: https://warrenmoore.net/understanding-cmtime

Comment: Same stuff (other piece of sound): `duration:4.736 maxProgress:4.472`. What can be the reason? EDIT: Just saw you updated answer, I'll try other options

Comment: @kerd That's very interesting. Can you also use `CMTimeGetSeconds` to print the duration? And one more thing: Try a finer-grained callback value. Instead of 10 seconds, try `1.0/30.0`.

Comment: In first comment i wrote result from `CMTimeGetSeconds`. Sorry if it was not clear. Also `CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(10.0, NSEC_PER_SEC)` that I've tried was the finest grain - it took 10 nanoseconds instead of 0.01 of a second which I use in my original post.

Comment: Try `CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(1.0/30.0, NSEC_PER_SEC)`. In your first comment the maxProgress was lower than the duration. In the question is was *higher* than the duration. So it could be that the callback just didn't fire because it wasn't fine-grained enough.

Comment: @kerd Actually checking `CMTimeGetSeconds(self.player.currentTime)` is more accurate than using the passed-in `time`, since that is actually the time when the block was invoked.

Comment: same result. sorry.

Answer (score 0):

The docs clearly state:

> You must retain the returned value as long as you want the time observer to be invoked by the player.

Comment: Sorry, but could you assist with further clearance of how this information can help? Btw, isn't the observer already invoked?

Comment: He's saying you need to hold a strong reference to the observer object otherwise it will be released. For example your UIViewController could have a property called playerTimeObserver.